# Nested Validation in Catel

Tags: validation, nested, tabcontrol, catel

On my Catel Tab Control I have 3 tab items. Each have Views and ViewModels and has validation. They are also 3 different things (with nothing in common, btw). When my View with the Tab Control is displayed, no validation errors are detected. Only when I click on a tab item and the tab item content has a validation error, am I alerted about the validation error.

Does the tab control provide a way to indicate if a tab item has validation errors (red square around the tab item header like with a text box that failed validation)?

I want to know about validation errors I have on tab items that are not visible without having to go through each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TabControl is a very complex control in WPF. Note that it will only show the current tab, not the other views (they will be unloaded).

To solve this, Catel provides its own TabControl where you can set the behavior of the tabs:

1. LazyLoading => Load all tabs using lazy loading, but keeps the tabs in memory afterwards.
2. LazyLoadingUnloadOthers => Load all tabs using lazy loading. As soon as a tab is loaded, all other loaded tabs will be unloaded.
3. EagerLoading => Load all tabs as soon as the tab control is loaded.
4. EagerLoadingOnFirstUse => Load all tabs when any of the tabs is used for the first time.

For more information, see https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/TabControl

Comment: Awesome! that works perfectly! Thanks. I have 2 other questions, though; how can I get similar functionality on nested user controls, especially if I have a command button that changes a property on that nested control which must cause a validation check on the outer usercontrol? Then, is there a way you can style the red border of the tab control that shows validation errors so that it is around the specific tab item and not the whole control?

Comment: If you want to do that, you will have to style the tab items (headers) and work with validation adorners, but that is a whole new topic. About the nested validation: we have a command that can be created using IValidationSummary. It should automatically re-evaluate state for you. Search the docs for it please, don't remember the exact name.

Comment: Cool thanks. I did have a look at the IValidationSummary before. I came across this discussion a few days ago: https://catel.codeplex.com/discussions/283521 and had a look at the sample at the end, but could not get it to work. I'll have a look again. I'm trying something with the InterestedIn attribute as well